# choosing an application framework to handle offline analysis with web requests

Tags: python, web

I am trying to design a web based app at the moment, that involves requests being made by users to trigger analysis of their previously entered data. The background analysis could be done on the same machine as the web server or be run on remote machines, and should not significantly impede the performance of the website, so that other users can also make analysis requests while the background analysis is being done. The requests should go into some form of queueing system, and once an analysis is finished, the results should be returned and viewable by the user in their account.

Please could someone advise me of the most efficient framework to handle this project? I am currently working on Linux, the analysis software is written in Python, and I have previously designed dynamic sites using Django. Is there something compatible with this that could work?

Answer (score 0):

Given your background and the analysys code already being written in Python, Django + Celery seems like an obvious candidate here. We're currently using this solution for a very processing-heavy app with one front-end django server, one dedicated database server, and two distinct celery servers for the background processing. Having the celery processes on distinct servers keeps the djangon front responsive whatever the load on the celery servers (and we can add new celery servers if required).

So well, I don't know if it's "the most efficient" solution but it does work.